Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() when running cron
I am getting this error when running cron.php on a Magento 1.9 site that I recently migrated to a new server. Everything was working correctly on the old one, now I get the error below:
Call to undefined function simplexml_load_file() in var/www/app/Mage.php:767

Line 767 on that file is as follows:
$localConfig = simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile);

I used function_exists('simplexml_load_file') right above that line and that came out true. I also checked that I have have all the required libraries in place. I also tried to run the cron.php file using a terminal (I am on a Plesk server) and it worked just fine.
Current environment:

Plesk 18.0.64 on AlmaLinux 8.10
PHP 7.1.33
Apache + nginx

The setup is the same as the old server, I just migrated to a more powerful machine.
Anyone with an idea of what is going on here? What am  missing?

I have the same issue. All needed functions are installed and when I execute the command manually, everything works as expected. When the script is executed by the cronjob I get the same error in my logs like @swiss_blade.

Tried cron.sh? (btw ... I'd highly recommend to update php to at least 7.4 and head over to OpenMage)

Make sure the cron command is running the same version of PHP that you use on the command line. Usually with the servers that support multiple versions of PHP by configuration, the php command is loaded dynamically when the console starts, but that not happens on the cron command.
Check the path to the PHP binary you are using on the CLI whereis php and use that to call the cron entry (something like /opt/php/bin/php71-cli or similar).
On the docs says:

A function name may exist even if the function itself is unusable due to configuration or compiling options (with the image functions being an example).

Can it be that the function is disabled within the with the disable_functions ini directive also.

Yes, the versions are the same. I also tried giving the full path to the PHP executable, just in case, but no luck...

are you invoking cron.php directly on the cron entry or using cron.sh script?

I tried both, but both exhibit the same behavior...

@swiss_blade check my edited response
